# Screen irreproducably turns black with Ubuntu 22.04 on Mac Pro 6,1

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, 22.04

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Mac Pro 6,1 and everything works smooth so far. However after some time while running (can be 1 minute or 1 hour) the screen turns black and says "no hdmi input" and I have to reboot the system.
It shouldn't be a driver problem:

```
sudo lshw -c video
configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
```

The exact specs are

```
Processor: Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz × 12    
Graphics: AMD® Tahiti
Memory: 16GB
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the `/var/log/syslog` file to see if there are messages about the video subsystem reporting errors? If the video signal is cutting out while the system is being used, that could point to thermal problems 

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any hint what to search for in the file? I am kind of overwhelmed by all the log entries

Comment: The simplest way to go through the log is to note what time your video cuts out. Once you know this, you can reboot and then check the logs for events around that time to see if there are any messages. This will give you a starting point to begin the investigation of the cause and any possible solution 

Comment: I was able to single out one of the instances, it starts with this                                       `May 12 13:58:23 evoecolab-MacPro kernel: [79553.489893] pcieport 0000:00:03.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
May 12 13:58:23 evoecolab-MacPro kernel: [79553.489899] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:   device [8086:0e08] error status/mask=00004000/00000000
May 12 13:58:23 evoecolab-MacPro kernel: [79553.489902] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:    [14] CmpltTO                (First) `

Comment: I can find [only one other report on the entire Internet of a similar issue](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=156835), which will make offering a solution rather difficult. The non-fatal PCIe bus error can point to either an incorrect driver, an aggressive power management setting (cutting power prematurely), or a kernel timing issue. Given the rareness of the report, I would lean towards a driver issue. One way to test would be to boot into a Live USB session and use it for a few hours to try and recreate the problem 

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort. I think I have connected the issue to R Studio. I am creating complex plots atm which need around 5 minutes per plot. The issue seems to be if more than one of these is loaded into the workspace. I'll try the USB session, thanks!